# How many objects are available for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
class Cardboard{
    Short story = 200;
    Cardboard go(Cardboard cb){
        cb = null;
        return cb;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Cardboard c1 = new Cardboard();
        Cardboard c2 = new Cardboard();
        Cardboard c3 = c1.go(c2);
        c1 = null;      
    }
}
```

After `go()` is executed `c2` should be pointing towards `null`, as implied by the method.This reference of `c2` is passed to `c3` variable, which again is pointing to `null` only thus `c2`'s object must be available for garbage collection.

Comment: No, `c2` won't be null. The parameter `cb` will be null inside the method, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Depending on the JVM / GC implementation, all of c1, c2 and c3 *may be* available to be garbage collected.  And maybe even `args` and any strings that it refers to.  Questions like this never have a clear-cut answer, and they are generally best not asked in the first place!!

Comment: Why c2 is not null?Reference(copy of c2) is passed in the go() and it makes cb(which is c2)

Comment: It's not a copy of `c2`s reference.

Comment: A whole new object reference gets placed on the stack in a completely different stack frame

Comment: @KrishnanMishra - The assignment `cb = null` does not change the value of `c2`.  Java is not call by reference.

Comment: They both point to the same object, but that doesn't mean they are the same reference

Comment: @CraigR8806 - The contents of `c2` and `cb` are the same reference (at least to start with).  The real explanation is that `c2` and `cb` are not the same variable!!  Therefore assigning a new value to one does not affect the other.  The references are the values ...

Comment: @StephenC I think we are saying the same thing, but you have a better way of explaining it

Comment: Well yes.  But using the correct words is critically important.  Easpecially when explaining things to beginners who are liable to get even more confused. That's why I corrected your .... misstatement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's incorrect.  When you pass an object to a method as a parameter, it passes a reference to that object and nothing more.  The reference, `cb`, to the object  becomes null, but `c2` is still a reference to that same object, so Java still recognizes that the object on the heap has one reference in the code pointing to it:  `c2`.

As Holger pointed out in a comment below, **ALL** of the objects in this particular snippet are eligible for garbage collection as they are not being used.  Java's GC has multiple methods for determining whether an object is eligible to be collected and just the fact that a reference exists that points to the object doesn't shield it from collection, however usage of that object would.

Comment: "...it passes a reference to that object...": [Java is pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: Yes the value is a reference

Comment: Java cannot literally pass the object the way that it is structured.  It will pass a reference to the object as a value.  Not the object itself

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that still *all of them* are eligible for garbage collection, as contrary to popular belief, the presence of references is irrelevant to the definition of “garbage”. All that matters, is, whether the object is subsequently used and here, none of the objects is used after the invocation of `go`. Actually, they are unused right from the start, i.e. even before the invocation of `go`, as shuffling around references is not an actual use of the object. Checking for references is only one, simple way to determine that an object can’t be used anymore. But there are others

Comment: @Holger Thanks! Updated my answer with your info